# Monitoring script to send email after disk usage reaches certain threshold

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a requirement where i need to monitor multiple directories for disk usage and if it reaches 90%, an email has to be sent. Also, the requirement is to list top 5 files along with owner who have consumed most space.I have come up with the script where I am sending email for each directory but i need a single email to capture all details. not sure how to attain that. any help is appreciated.

when i tried to look for top 5 files using the command

```
du -hsx /var/tmp | sort -rh | head -10
```

getting below error.

```
du: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:

#!/bin/bash
host=`hostname`
DIRLIST=(/tmp /tmp/abc /data/cbn /var/ttt /var/ttty )
for dir in "${DIRLIST[@]}"
do
  tst=`df $dir | tail --lines=+2 | sed s/%//g | awk '{ if($5 > 90) print $5;}'`
  if [ "$tst" != "" ] ; then
     msg=`df -h $dir | head --lines=+2 | sed s/%//g| awk '{ if($5 > 90) print $6,"     ",$5;}'`
    (echo "Below Directory on $host has crossed the threshold limit of 90%. Please Take necessary action."; echo ; echo "$msg"; )| mailx -vvv -s "Disk Space Alert on : $host" -r "FROM ADDRESS" "TO ADDRESS"
fi

done
```

Comment: add another variable to "build up" your final msg, i.e. `finalMsg="$finalMsg $msg"` AND move your `(echo ... ) | mail ...` line to be outside of the loop. That should be the last thing that gets executed. BUT warning, getting a correctly formatted message captured inside of a `"$variable"` can be very tricky. I'd recommend redirecting output into tmp files and then sending final file via email, again from outside of the loop. `mail -s ... users@places.com < /tmp/finalEmailMsg` is the general idea. (And of course, cleanup the /tmp files just before  you exit). Good luck.

Comment: Also, learn to use `awk` to it's full capabilities. `tst=...` can be rewritten as `tst=$(du | awk 'NR>1{gsub(/%/,""); if ($5 > 90) print $6,"   ", $5}')` or very close to that. Work your way thru https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html to improve your `awk`i-tude. ;-). Good luck.

Comment: Hi Shellter, Thank you for the response. But my question is how do i build that finalMsg. if there are 3 directories that breach the threshold, how will add them up to finalMsg? I am not sure how to capture that

Comment: add the `finalMsg="$finalMsg $msg"` to you existing code, move the `echo .. | mail` line outside of the loop and see what you get. You'll have to experiement. Make as many extra variables as you need and then combine them all like currMsg="$msg1 $msg2 $msg2"` then `finalMsg="$finalMsg $currMsg"`. Until you get it to generate the messages you need, don't bother sending an email, just `echo "$finalMsg"` after the loop is done. Good luck.

Comment: Hello Shellter, I understood what you are saying but hard coding them is a bad practice right? Also, if i need to add few more directories, i need to change the code again. what i was looking for was using array to capture all violations. In python we can create a list and start appending the result to the list. I was looking for something like that

Comment: `currMsg="$msg1 $msg2 $msg3"` is only sort of hardcoding, as the values of the indivual variables may/should change thru each cycle of the loop you are using, right? But that was offered as an alternative to running `finalMsg="$finalMsg $msg"` because you didn't seem to like that. But that provides just what you ask for, an extendable list, notice that the first time that code would be executed, there is no value for `$finalMsg`. It is only after it has executed multiple times will it build up to a list of messages. That is why I encourage you to try it, rather than trying to think it thru. GL

Comment: OR, again, I encourage you to experiment with `/tmp` files (that you clean up at the end of the script ;-)). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you let me try that and keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks Shellter, I was able to achieve the desired result. I followed what you suggested and it worked. Thank you for your help

Comment: Good show! Glad you solved your problem Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all your help.